# Failed logon to an application via AD

Tags: login, active-directory

My problem at work is we use an application which authenticates via AD. The application processes an event within it, and user must authenticate thru AD. The problem is this application will routinely fail to authenticate and throw the following message:

> The login could not be confirmed. Please try again or click Cancel to exit.

Clearly this is a generic error message and any google search will not help to determine the source of it.

I can't share details on the application as this would divulge proprietary info. A script of my logons/off doesn't reveal anything when it fails. Any ideas on how I could capture this event? I am looking for something that would give me information on why the logon was rejected.

Comment: Looked in the event viewer?

Comment: Checked the network calls being sent/received? (LDAP? Netlogon? Kerberos?)

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking through some of the causes of failed logon - maybe the application can't find the directory or is caching something or is mangling the credentials process. Does it fail immediately or is it timing out?

Comment: the mention of directory is what is interesting me. Here are the details:

Comment: the mention of directory is what is interesting me. Here are the details: When it works it is immediate, when it fails it too is immediate. In fact, it can't be called a failure in that the credentials are never authenticated, they are rejected before submission. And to prove it was rejecting. I purposely entered the wrong pwd and was rejected, and then repeated the process with the right one and was accepted, when the process is working. So, what I am implying is credentials are sometimes sent to AD recognized and authenticated, but on other occasions sent and not recognized and rejected.

Comment: A colleague has asked me to try to view the LDAP settings for the application, but I'm not sure if I can access these settings.